# Appending information to an XML file in VB.NEt

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
<Setting1>
   <SubSetting1>Test1</SubSetting1>
   <SubSetting2>Test2</SubSetting2>
</Setting1>
<Setting2>
   <SubSetting1>Test3</SubSetting1>
   <SubSetting2>Test4</SubSetting2>
</Setting2>
```

This is just a small example for reference to an xml document. I am trying to learn how to append an existing xml document, with out writing over the xml tag. My actual xml document has more nodes (about 40) and I am putting all of the new values (in place of Test1, Test2, ..etc) into a list. In the correct order, So I was thinking using a For loop to just write the value.

something like this?

```
Public Sub example (ListofSettings As List(of String))
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
    Dim myNodes, myChildren As XmlNodeList
    settingsFile.Load(SETTINGS_FILE_PATH)
    myNodes = settingsFile.GetElementsByTagName("Settings1")
For i as Integer = 0 to ListofSettings.count
For Each n As XmlNode In myNodes
        If n.Name = "Settings1" Then
            myChildren = n.ChildNodes
            For Each n1 As XmlNode In myChildren
                Select Case n1.Name
                    Case "SubSetting1"
                        writer.WriteElementString(**DONT WANT TO CHANGE TAG NAME**, ListofSettings.Item(i))
End Select
Next
End if    
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xmldocument.SelectSingleNode and change the innerXml of the node that you want. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) for an example