# Append data to existing XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

This is my code for Appending New Records to my existing XML Document:

```vb
Sub addEXISTING(ByVal c_name As String, ByVal c_age As Integer, ByVal c_sex As String)
     Dim e_client = doc.CreateElement("CLIENT")

     Dim e_name As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("NAME")

     Dim e_age As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("AGE")

     Dim e_sex As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("SEX")

     e_name.InnerText = c_name
     e_age.InnerText = c_age
     e_sex.InnerText = c_sex
     e_client.AppendChild(e_name)
     e_client.AppendChild(e_age)
     e_client.AppendChild(e_sex)
     childparent.AppendChild(e_client)

     doc.AppendChild(childparent)
     doc.Save("D:\mefolder\me.xml")
     MsgBox("XML DOCUMENT UPDATED!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Notice:")
End Sub
```

But when ever this piece of code is executed, the file entries of the new data overwrite the existing ones.

Basically, the output I would like is this, for example (when viewing the XML document in a browser):

```
<BIO_INFO>
<CLIENT>   ----- EXISTING 
<NAME>John</NAME> 
<AGE>21</AGE>
<SEX>MALE</SEX>
</CLIENT>
<CLIENT>  ----- NEW ENTRY
<NAME>Elena</NAME>
<AGE>21</AGE>
<SEX>FEMALE</SEX>
</CLIENT>
</BIO_INFO>
```

But this is what I get:

```
<BIO_INFO>
<CLIENT>
<NAME>Elena</NAME>
<AGE>21</AGE>
<SEX>FEMALE</SEX>
</CLIENT>
</BIO_INFO>"
```

Here are my declarations:

```vb
Dim filer As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("D:\mefolder")
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
Dim root As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("CLIENT")
Dim childparent As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("BIO_INFO")
Dim child As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("NAME")
Dim childage As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("AGE")
Dim childsex As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("SEX")
```

Comment: You can try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237514/appending-information-to-an-xml-file-in-vb-net?rq=1
  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645440/appending-an-existing-xml-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to append data to xml document. You need to load the whole document and save it again (from nianios comment [Appending an existing XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2645440/669527)). It is necessary to use [XmlDocument.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx)

```
Sub addEXISTING(ByVal c_name As String, ByVal c_age As Integer, ByVal c_sex As String)

    XmlDocument.Load("D:\mefolder\me.xml")'!

   Dim e_client = doc.CreateElement("CLIENT")
   Dim e_name As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("NAME")
   Dim e_age As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("AGE")
   Dim e_sex As Xml.XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("SEX")

   e_name.InnerText = c_name
   e_age.InnerText = c_age
   e_sex.InnerText = c_sex
   e_client.AppendChild(e_name)
   e_client.AppendChild(e_age)
   e_client.AppendChild(e_sex)
   childparent.AppendChild(e_client)

   doc.AppendChild(childparent)
   doc.Save("D:\mefolder\me.xml")
  MsgBox("XML DOCUMENT UPDATED!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Notice:")
End Sub
```

Please be aware that this opening and saving for every record is not very efficient especially when the document is large. Consider taking `.Save` and `.Load` out of your method and trigger them separately (like you are processing a text file in a text editor).